# Enthought style virtualenv in Anaconda

Tags: python, virtualenv, anaconda, canopy, conda

I am familiar with creating virtualenv with Enthought Canopy's `venv` command. One of the features that i like about it is the `--system-site-packages` option which allows me to link all my system libraries to the new environment. Hence allowing me to create "light" environments. This saves a lot of disk space when creating multiple environments. I am trying to find a similar option with `conda` but it seem to me that it doesn't provide such an option. Is there anyway to create canopy like virtual environments with anaconda?

Answer (score 1):

conda's environments are isolated from each other and the system. Normally you should not try to access packages from a different environment. This defeats the whole purpose of virtual environments.

That said, conda's environments are by design light weight. If you have two environments using the same interpreter and the same version of a package, only one physical package will exist on your hard drive. The individual environments merely link to the physical package.

Comment: I created a virtualenv with conda specifying the packages numpy, matplotlib, scipy, pandas and basemap to be installed. The directory with the new environment is 572MB in size! Am i doing something wrong? I already have these installed in the main env. I ran: ``conda create -n test numpy matplotlib pandas scipy basemap``.

Comment: conda uses hard links. So counting the total file size is tricky. IIRC all environments are per default light weight, but I am not so sure anymore.

Comment: I noticed that during the create and remove phase ``conda`` talks about linking and unlinking, so maybe what you are talking about makes sense. But then when i tried to compare the "inodes" of the files (``ls -lia``) in numpy between the root installation and the virtual environment they didn't match. I don't know what to make of that.

Comment: the linking will only work if both packages are from the same python version and also the same package version. But they are, they definitely should be the same physical file.